# How sum a column in Entity Framework using linq and join it with another table

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the following `StockTransaction` table.
Every thing that come and goes into stock with a particular brand is recorded in this table so I need to know the amount of goods that entered the stock and vice versa.

e.g: 10 T-shirt with Adidas brand entered the stock and 5 sold therefor 5 T-shirt should be remain in stock.

and I want to sum the `Quantity` column according to `GoodsID` column and `Input` column

[image]

And I join it with `GoodsBrand` table.

Note: there is no relationship between `StockTransaction` table and `GoodsBrand` table. I only want to join `StockTransation` with `GoodsBrand` to get goods with its particular brand.

[image]

I want something like this:

[image]

Any solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That answer you've linked to **IS** Linq ..... not sure what else you expect to get as "Linq" ...

Comment: @marc_s I edited the question could you please see it again?

Comment: This is question is unclear. Please, explain the relation between your tables and how you come to your result table. What is this GoodsBrand table? Also consider naming all your tables. What is the name of your first table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kind of fuzzy to say that this can be the shorter version:

```cs
var result = transactions
    .Join(goodbBrands,
        tr => tr.GoodsID,
        gb => gb.GoodsID,
        ((transaction, brand) => new
        {
            transaction,
            brand
        }))
    .Join(goods,
        gbs => gbs.transaction.GoodsID,
        g => g.ID,
        (gbs, good) => new
        {
            Brand = gbs.brand,
            Transaction = gbs.transaction,
            Good = good
        })
    .Join(brands,
        gb => gb.Brand.BrandID,
        b => b.ID,
        ((gbs, brds) => new
        {
            Brand = brds,
            Good = gbs.Good,
            Transaction = gbs.Transaction
        })).Select(item => new
    {
        GoodsName = item.Good.Name,
        Brand = item.Brand.Name,
        Qty = item.Transaction.Quantity
    });
```

but actually it would be much better to create correct model relations for the Tables using the Entity Framework [Navigation Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/relationships#:%7E:text=Navigation%20properties%20provide%20a%20way,relationship%20in%20which%20it%20participates.) with the `Include` for [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data).

This way the above massive query can become far simpler:

```cs
var res = transactions.Include(tr => brands)
    .Include(tr => goods)
    .Select( ... );
```

Answer (score 0):

For selecting the quantity, you should be able to do:

```
firstTable.Where(x => x.Input).GroupBy(x => x.GoodsID).Select(x => x.Sum(y => y.Quantity));
```

I'll leave the join as an exercise, as it is well documented.